# How to calculate the size of list in a velocity template?

Tags: java, html, list, velocity

How to calculate list size in velocity template? I am using velocity 1.4.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: `list.size()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html If that's not what you mean then you'll have to provide more detail.

Comment: THis is what you need :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747254/how-to-access-get-the-size-of-an-array-collection-in-velocity-templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you mean "how do you call java methods in in the velocity template" because the method you are looking for is on the "List" javadoc, already mentioned.

I believe this article would be helpful:

[How to access/get the size of an array/collection in velocity templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747254/how-to-access-get-the-size-of-an-array-collection-in-velocity-templates)

To save you a read, you should just be able to input this:

> ${myArrayList.size()}

Answer (score -1):

list.size() "Return with list size value Datatype 'Integer'"